# In Google Sheets, can the IF function handle a query as both arguments?

Tags: google-sheets

What I've tried...

1. Various syntax variations
2. Google searches

What I'd like, in simple terms...

=IF(B2=" ",QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE H = '"&A3&"'"),QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE H = '"&A3&"' AND A = '"&A4&"'"))

In other words, if B2 is blank, return ALL results; otherwise, return results based on the text found in B2.

The formula DOES work if both A3 and A4 have values. It does NOT work if A4 is blank.

I can't share the sheet (gov't data), sorry, but hopefully I've explained the issue clearly enough.

Now I'm thinking that maybe a FILTER function would be better?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`IF` it:

```
=IF(B2="", 
 QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE 9=9 "&
 IF(A3="",," and H = '"&A3&"'")),
 QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE 9=9 "&
 IF(A3="",," and H = '"&A3&"'")&
 IF(A4="",," and A = '"&A4&"'")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did't include the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I recreated a demo sheet similar to yours.

[image]

**Use this formula**

```
=IF(B2="",
 QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE H = '"&A3&"'"),
 QUERY(RawData!$A$2:$I, "SELECT A,B,C,D,E WHERE H = '"&A3&"' AND A = '"&A4&"'"))
```

### Result

**1 - When `B2` is Empty `""`**

[image]

**2 - When `B2` is Not Empty**

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Honestly, that is 99% of what I had originally. I must have had an extra apostrophe or something in the formula. Thanks again!

Comment: I failed to mention that A3 and A4 are the same as B1 and B2, but A3 forces the keyword into lowercase (because I'm using a REGEXEXTRACT formula elsewhere and it's case-sensitive), and A4 forces uppercase, since all aircraft registration numbers are coded in upper case (e.g. N326KW). Sorry for any confusion

Comment: if you can include you example demo, may be you don't have to use multiple cells, use a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/), or a screenshot.